# Where should I add "forcefully" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, adverb-position

> Her lips curled up forcefully at the ends.
>
> Her lips forcefully curled up at the ends.

Which is the most correct/idiomatic option? And why?

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: Do you mean "forcefully" rather than "forcibly"? That seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: @Deepak Oh, yes I edited the question.

Comment: How is this forcing occurring?  This sentence makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sentence

> Her lips curled up forcefully at the ends.

you're applying the adverb 'forcefully' to the phrase 'at the ends' which I don't believe is the intention.

The second sentence

> Her lips forcefully curled up at the ends.

the adverb 'forcefully' applies to the curling up of her lips. I assume your intention is to convey that her lips curled in a strong manner.

[Forcefully](http://In%20a%20strong%20and%20assertive%20manner;%20vigorously.) -

> Forcefully - In a strong and assertive manner; vigorously.